# On Riemann's extended zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\xi$  be Riemann's  extended zeta function.

Can any one calculate $\xi(-\frac{2\pi k }{\ln 2}i)$   for $k \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}$?

P.S. It really seems that $\xi(-\frac{2\pi k }{\ln 2}i)=0$.

Comment: What (or which) extended zeta function do you mean?

Comment: @anomaly: See [Riemann $\xi$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_Xi_function).

Comment: I don't know of a closed form for $\xi(kt)$ for $t = -2\pi i/\log 2$ and nonzero $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, but it's not zero (unless you've disproved the Riemann hypothesis). The $\Gamma$ function is nonzero everywhere, and $kt$ has real part $0$.

Comment: @ anomaly   You are right :  $\xi(-\frac{2\pi k}{\ln2}i )\neq 0$. But wether can be calculated   $\xi(-\frac{2\pi k}{\ln2} i) $?